# Move files from Microsoft 2008 file server to GDrive

Tags: google-drive

I manage the It for small company around 30 employees and we have just recently moved from Exchange to Gmail apps. We have a file server (MS 2008)  with around 150MB of files dating back to 6 years ago. My plan was to move possibly just files from the last 3 years as these would include current contracts, invoices etc. The reason for moving to G drive is; one accessibility but also cost. I have read other posts that highlight various negative points about this but I don't want this to become a discussion on why but how. Permissions on the files isn't big issue, so how would I transfer the files form the server to G drive? and is there any way to conver them to google docs automatically ?

Any help would be weclome.

Comment: It's better to limit your question post to a single question.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get your files into Google Drive is to install the [Google Drive app](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375078), either on the server or on a PC that has access to the files.

> 1. Go to http://drive.google.com New Window.
> 2. Click **Connect Drive to your desktop** below the list of Drive views on the left side of the screen.
> 3. Click **Download Google Drive for your PC**.
> 4. Open **googledrivesync.exe** to automatically install and start Google Drive on your PC. (You may receive a warning that Google Drive is an application downloaded from the Internet. Click the **Open** button.)
> 5. Enter your **Google Account username and password** in the window that opens. This will be the account associated with Google Drive for your PC.
> 6. Complete the installation package instructions.
> 7. Launch Google Drive for your PC from the Start menu. Drag files and folders into your Google Drive folder to begin syncing items to **My Drive** (part of Google Drive on the web).

Then once that is installed, it's just a question of moving or copying the files from their currently location into the special Google Drive folder that's been created. The app will automatically upload the files in the background.